# Turn Off Windows 10 Touchscreen

Tags: windows-10, laptop, touchscreen

Friday morning = doing someone in the office a favor trying to fix their windows 10 laptop.

The touchscreen is registering inputs despite not being touched.

There is no obvious damage / dirt and we can't stop the digitizer from sending these false touches.

We can't even login because the touches cancel the process before we can enter the password!

We have tried using an external screen with the lid closed but the touches still trigger!

Without logging in I can't get to device manager to disable the touchscreen driver.

I have tried safe mode but the touch screen is active there too!

Any ideas?

Only thing I can think of is to take it apart and unplug / replace the digitizer.

The owner doesn't really care about the laptop as it is quite old and only used by the kids to play games etc. Losing the touch functionality is fine but they are not going to spend any real money on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try F8 to enter safe mode. Safe mode loads only the bare minimum hardware support.

Answer (score -1):

Reasons for ghosts in your touchscreen may be :

1. Temperature issues
2. Loose connection
3. Damaged or wrong drivers

A loose connection is the most likely explanation, or some other hardware problem,
but below are some manipulations that might help.

**Calibrate the touchscreen**

- Open Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Tablet PC Settings
- Click *Calibrate the screen for pen or touch input*
- Under "Display options," select the display (if applicable).
- Select Touch input
- In the white screen, tap the crosshair each time that is appears on the screen
- Save the calibration data.

**Diagnostics**

Some computer manufacturers include a diagnostic program that tests various
hardware components, including the touchscreen.

**Disable and enable the touchscreen**

- Open Device Manager > Human Interface Devices > expand it
- Right-click on *HID-compliant Touch Screen* and choose Disable
- Repeat, but this time choose Enable.

**Drivers**

Search for newer drivers on the website of the manufacturer of the computer.
As you say that this is an old computer, there might not be any.

Comment: Downvoted. Why ?

Comment: Probably because "We can't even login because the touches cancel the process before we can enter the password!" invalidates all of your answer. If the OP cannot login then none of your suggestions work.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I did say that the likeliest reason is hardware. The rest is in case he manages somehow to boot. The manufacturer diagnostics also often come as a boot CD.

Answer (score -2):

You could try to get in the BIOS/UEFI setup and disable the touchscreen there. Usually there is an option to disable the touchpad of the laptop, it is possible that there is an option for the touchscreen.

Since I can't comment on the other answer: It is well written, but since the problem with the touchscreen doesn't even allow to login it doesn't really help in this case.